# Why is not this multidimensional array displaying properly?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm figuring this problem:
I have the `$_POST['user']` variable. If I `print_r` this variable I get:

```
Array (
  ['name'] => Your name 
  ['phone'] => Your phone number 
  ['email'] => Your email
)
```

But if I try to use `$_POST['user']['name']`, nothing happens, it's an empty value.

It also happens if I set `$_POST['user']` to a variable, for example `$user`, when I `print_r $user` I get the same array result, but if I try to work with `$user['name']` it's blank.

This is the input data that has been submited

```
<input type="text" name="user['name']" value="Your name" class="general-user user-name-style" />
<input type="text" name="user['phone']" value="Your phone number" class="general-user user-data" />
<input type="text" name="user['email']" value="Your email" class="general-user user-data right-user" />
```

Am I working around in a wrong way with arrays?

Comment: Your approach looks ok, please share some code.

Comment: If `$_POST['user']['name']` didn't exist, a warning/error would have been displayed. Your value is empty.

Comment: But when I print_r $_POST['user'], it shows me the value I submited "Your name", when I echo/print_r it directly, it shows nothing

Comment: @i.am.michiel, the code is as simple as this

print_r($_POST['user']);
//Displays things correctly
print_r($_POST['user']['name']);
//Nothing is shown

Comment: @i.am.michiel depending on error_reporting and display_errors, and it's only a notice. The default PHP config is rather unfriendly in this regard AFAIR.

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos what does print_r($_POST); display?

Comment: @Bugs, it displays: Array ( [user] => Array ( ['name'] => Your name ['phone'] => Your phone ['email'] => Your email ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apostrophes are included in the keys, i.e. you get "'name'" as opposed to "name".
Try $_POST['user']["'name'"]

To solve the problem, remove the apostrophes from your HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="user[name]" value="Your name" class="general-user user-name-style" />
<input type="text" name="user[phone]" value="Your phone number" class="general-user user-data" />
<input type="text" name="user[email]" value="Your email" class="general-user user-data right-user" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check, maybe "name" has Cyrillic or other than regular Latin "a" or "e".